# Assigning / Unassigning classes to objects

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to assign / unassign classes to some objects, that would then get certain CSS styles set, for example a class for active links, that would set their font-style to 'italic'.

I wrapped a function around that functionality, so I can call it on every object with every classname. The function checks whether the classname is already present in the class attribute. If not so, it appends the classname.

The following is an 'input' that should change color from grey(inactive) to black(active), if the parent div is hovered, triggering 'overSearch()'. Within that function, 'assignClass()' is called, overpassing the 'input' object and the desired classname.

HOWEVER, I'm getting errors as follows:

> "Cannot read property 'innerText' of null."

If I delete '.innerText', it says:

> "Cannot read property 'indexof' of undefined."

HTML

```
<input id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="http://" spellcheck="false"/>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var srchBar = document.getElementById('searchbar');

function assignClass(obj, classStr){
    var cls = obj.getAttribute('class').innerText;
    if ( cls.indexof(classStr) == (-1) ) {
        cls += (' ' + classStr);
    }
}

function overSearch(){
    assignClass(srchBar, 'searchActive');
}
```

CSS

```
.searchActive {
    color: black !important;
}
```

My attempts of explaining the errors is that 'assignClass()' cannot read the 'class' attribute because it's null (initially).
Other error sources could be incorrect handling of the DOM structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that particular DOM node does not have a `class` attribute so `obj.getAttribute('class')` will return `null`, and accessing a property on that will throw.

Instead, use the [`.className` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className) of the DOM element, which always does exist. Dealing with attribute nodes is unnecessary for nearly all tasks.

```
function addClass(el, classStr){
    var cls = el.className
    if (cls.indexof(classStr) == -1)
        el.className = cls + ' ' + classStr;
}
```

Notice that `cls` is a string variable, not a pointer to some property. You will need to assign explicitly to the DOM, changing the variable is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

use `.classList`

```
var srchBar = document.getElementById('searchbar');

function assignClass(obj, classStr){
    obj.classList.add(classStr);
}

function overSearch(){
    assignClass(srchBar, 'searchActive');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/W7MhL/

As you can see, you may also just drop your own function and use plain js instead.